# Setting Up A Potential Excel Macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm not even sure if this is something you would use a macro to do the second question.

I have a spreadsheet of a list of cards in a card game I play on the PC. So this leads to two questions.

1) Column E is for legendaries. If the column value = 1, then I want the row to be filled a certain color. So IE: row 2, columns A, B, C,D,E all filled with orange.

2) How can I create a text link that will filter anything with a value in column E? Column E is only going to ever contain a "1" if it's present. I want to filter out all the values that are not one. Then how would I clear it?

You can download my Excel workbook if you wish from the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0x25Dj52eXBT1dlSFE1YjBXV0k/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

For the ***first question***, just use **conditional formatting**. Select your entire sheet, go to the `Home ribbon`, click "`Conditional Formatting`", then click "`New Rule`." Under "`Rule Type`," select "`Use a formula to determine which cells to format`". In the formula box, enter `=$E1=1`, then click "`Format`" to edit what you want those rows to look like. Hit "`OK`" and now all rows where `E=1` should be changed.

As for the ***second question***, the simplest way would be to select your header row, then go to the Data ribbon and click "**`Filter`**." The when you want to see your legendaries grouped together, simply click the drop-down arrow on column E's header and click "`Sort Largest to Smallest`." This way you can also sort by the other columns if you want (name, ID, whatever).

Comment: I tried the first paragraph and got no change out of it.

Edit: Nevermind, got it!